# Cannot assign any values to variables in VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My Visual Studio Code installation (v.1.59.1) is behaving strangely. Any command I type in the Terminal results in the error "The term 'myCommandHere' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."
[image]

This includes but is not limited to variable assignments, as per the above, although non-variable computations work.

I'm new to Python so I often try simple toy bits of code in the terminal to see if they'll work as expected. But since this problem appeared, I cannot use the Terminal for this, and need to run all code as .py scripts (which works fine).

I am on Windows 10, and VS is running with admin rights.

Comment: You need to type ```python``` or ```py``` to launch python interpreter. You are entering it in the command prompt, not in python interactive background

Comment: Ah, of course, thank you, knew this was a silly thing to ask!